# Jasperserver 6.3.0 drill through view throws MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, jasperserver

I have upgraded my jasperserver from 5.6 to 6.3 after that, i observed that OLAP
  View Report's drill through view throws MySQL syntax error.

Here is the error

```
select `sales_territories`.`country_name` as `Country`, 
`sales_territories`.`territory_name` as `Territory`, `lob`.`lob_name` as 
`LOB`, `lob`.`sublob_name` as `Sub_LOB`, `customers`.`cust_name` as 
`Customer`, `customers`.`industry` as `Domain`, 
`project_bill_loc`.`pbl_name` as `Bill_Location`, `projects`.`project_name` 
as `Project`, `resources`.`resource_name` as `resnames`, 
`res_lvl`.`level_code` as `code`, `res_lvl`.`level_name` as `name`, 
`res_type`.`type_name` as `type`, `date_hierarchies`.`year` as `Year`, 
`date_hierarchies`.`quarter` as `Quarter`, `date_hierarchies`.`month` as 
`Month`, `facts_financials`.`m_rev` as `Reve from    
`olap_cubes`.`sales_territories` as `sales_territories`,   
`olap_cubes`.`facts_financials` as `facts_financials`, `olap_cubes`.`lob` as 
`lob`, `olap_cubes`.`customers` as `customers`, 
`olap_cubes`.`project_bill_loc` as `project_bill_loc`, 
`olap_cubes`.`projects` as `projects`, `olap_cubes`.`resources` as 
`resources`, 
`olap_cubes`.`res_lvl` as `res_lvl`, `olap_cubes`.`res_type` as `res_type`, 
`date_hierarchies` as `date_hierarchies` where `facts_financials`.`d_slter` 
= `sales_territories`.`id` and `facts_financials`.`d_lob` = `lob`.`id` and 
`lob`.`lob_name` = 'AS' and `facts_financials`.`d_cust` = `customers`.`id` 
and `customers`.`cust_name` = 'American Financial Resources, Inc.' and  
`facts_financials`.`d_pbl` = `project_bill_loc`.`id` and 
`facts_financials`.`d_prj` = `projects`.`id` and `projects`.`project_name` = 
'American Financial Resources: AFR B2B Sales Portal (P007725)' and 
`facts_financials`.`d_res` = `resources`.`id` and 
`facts_financials`.`d_reslvl` = `res_lvl`.`id` and 
`facts_financials`.`d_restype` = `res_type`.`id` and 
`facts_financials`.`date_id` = `date_hierarchies`.`id` and 
`date_hierarchies`.`year` = 2017 and `date_hierarchies`.`quarter` = DATE 
'2016-04-01' order by `sales_territories`.`country_name` ASC, 
`sales_territories`.`territory_name` ASC, `lob`.`lob_name` ASC, 
`lob`.`sublob_name` ASC, `customers`.`cust_name` ASC, `customers`.`industry` 
 ASC, `project_bill_loc`.`pbl_name` ASC, `projects`.`project_name` ASC, 
 `resources`.`resource_name` ASC, `res_lvl`.`level_code` ASC, 
`res_lvl`.`level_name` ASC, `res_type`.`type_name` ASC, 
`date_hierarchies`.`year` ASC, `date_hierarchies`.`quarter` ASC, 
`date_hierarchies`.`month` ASC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Horrible formatting. Please narrow down the problem to something readable, reproducible, understandable,... Try to put the statement in phpMyAdmin and remove everything that works until you come to the part that doesn't work.

Comment: @venkyMCA You have an error in query

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for your reply. I have identified that before from " ` " mark was missed

Comment: Why it was missed after upgrading jasperserver

Answer (score 1):

Comment

```
mondrian.rolap.generate.formatted.sql=true in /WEB-INF/classes/mondrain.properties
```

Comment: Actually I am a new user, I don't have enough reputations to comment on the above question. so I added as an answer.

Comment: Commenting `mondrian.rolap.generate.formatted.sql=true` in **/WEB-INF/classes/mondrain.properties** helped in fixing the issue.